# issue with .htaccess

Tags: php

i have 2 questions, the first being a problem...

1. This is my `.htaccess` file

   ```
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?get=$1
   RewriteRule ^somepage$ index.php?get=somepage
   ```

   it accepts and executes `mysite.com/index.php?get=somepage` but does not execute `mysite.com/somepage` even though they are the same thing, why is this and what is wrong?
2. When someone types `mysite.com/index.php?get=somepage` how can i either ignore or replace that request with `mysite.com/somepage`?

Answer (score 0):

First, this

> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?get=$1

should most probably be this

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?get=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will probably fix your second problem though I personally wouldn't worry about it. If people want to type in the long version of your rewritten URLs, let them.

For more information, see [`[L]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l) and [`[QSA]`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(\w+)/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?get=$1 [L,QSA]
```